# Android Button OnClick Error

Tags: android

I am trying to implement simple button click event but code errors out at compile time.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

Button button1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    addListenerOnButton();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) { 

        }
    });
}
}
```

The compiler gives error in `addListenerOnButton` method which is as follows:

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Remove import DialogInterface.OnClickListener and add import view.OnClickListener...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are creating a DialogInterface.OnClickListener when the method expects a View.OnClickListener.

Try:

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) { 

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 

    }
});
```

Change to

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) { 

    }
});
```

You are import invalid **OnClickListener**. **DialogInterface.OnClickListener** instead of **View.OnClickListener**.

Answer (score 3):

You have imported `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener`.

Either fix the imports or make the class you want explicit with `new View.OnClickListener() { ...`.